# Glib-GIO WARNING Unexpectedly, UWP app Problem

Tags: manim

I am using Manim.
Every time I render the animation, this message came out in the terminal

Should this concern my system?

(process:8884): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: 00:03:23.424: Unexpectedly, UWP app `AcerIncorporated.PredatorSenseV30_3.0.3138.0_x64__48frkmn4z8aw4' (AUMId` AcerIncorporated.PredatorSenseV30_48frkmn4z8aw4!CentenialConvert') supports 1 extensions but has no verbs

The file is perfectly rendered but it does not open automatically when I render it in 480p

If I will render the animation in 1080p, the warning still comes out first and the video runs automatically.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me as well when I render animations on Manim. It made no impact on my machine whatsoever, so I don't think you should be concerned.